# Force Sinatra to quit when hanging

Tags: sinatra

After a control - c to quit the server I get the message

```
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2015-06-21 16:38:58] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

and then it just hangs there and doesn't exit.  Is there a way to force it to quit?  I have to close the window, navigate back into the project and run the server again.  Is there a way to avoid having to do this - something to force it to quit?

Comment: Any information on the version, the code, your system…? This could be for so many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is crude, but this is how I solve it on my windows computer: Spam C-c. Eventually it fully closes.

If you're on Linux/MacOS you can install [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun). Shotgun is a gem that will automatically reload your server so you don't have to close and reopen every time you make a change.

Unfortunately it doesn't run on windows, so you're stuck with the crude method above if that's the case.